# Calabi Yau compactification based on U(1) charges

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, compactification, calabi-yau

In Green-Schwarz-Witten Volume 2, chapter 15, it is argued (roughly) that we need 6-dimensional manifolds  of $SU(3)$ holonomy in order to receive 1 covariantly constant spinor field. And it turns out that [Calabi Yau manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold) satisfy this property.

Now I understand this reasoning just fine, but I occasionally find in some papers, that Calabi Yau manifolds are "demanded" based on the fact that the sum of all $U(1)$ charges sums to 0? Could someone enlighten me on why this yields the Calabi Yau condition?

Comment: It can't be right, because you need the low energy SUSY requirement for CY, but there might be some meaning in this statement that I am missing. Do you remember the source?

Comment: I more or less found the answer I think. Gauge anomaly cancellation requires $c_2(V) = c_2(T)$ where $V$ is the gauge bundle and $T$ the tangent bundle. This expression can be given in terms of the $U(1)$ charges in certain cases

Comment: Can you post an answer?